# Scroll to top when checkbox is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I just wanted to know how I could get the page scrolled to top when checkbox is selected using jQuery or JavaScript, knowing that there is some Angular JS code in there.

```
<div class="checkbox-list">
  <div class="checkbox box-collapse-color" ng-repeat="Type in Types">
    <span class="count pull-right">{{Type.count}}</span>
    <input type="checkbox"
           ng-click="addCompanyType(Type.ac)" 
           id="checkbox1-c-{{$index}}" />
    <label class="check" for="checkbox1-c-{{$index}}">
      <span>{{Type.ac}}</span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is the following:

```
$window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

It seems the code should be placed into your `addCompanyType` function, but I can't say definitely. I'd suggest looking at Angular JS `ng-checked` directive. Do not forget to inject `$window`.